# How to set custom upload directory per user after moving content directory

Tags: uploads, directory, users

I set the content and the wordpress directory of wordpress like described [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php):

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content');
```

Now what I want to do is set an individual upload directory for every user, like this:

```
wpinstance.org/content/uploads/user-name/here-goes-the-file.jpg
```

I already tried a lot using

```
define( 'UPLOADS', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content/uploads'.$current_user->user_name.'/');
```

as well as many combinations without `dirname()` and so on. It all turned out to take the files up to `wordpress/…something` and leaving the user name part empty. So how can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need this: `$current_user->user_login`. Username is not an accepted value that I know of for WordPress core.

Comment: nope, sorry. that returns an empty string as well :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With credits to [petermolnar](/users/4209/petermolnar) via `irc://freenode.net/wordpress` I can answer my own question. The key is to set an `upload-dir` filter in the theme's `functions.php`:

```
function per_user_upload_dir( $original ){
    // use the original array for initial setup
    $modified = $original;
    // set our own replacements
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $subdir = $current_user->user_login;
        $modified['subdir'] = $subdir;
        $modified['url'] = $original['baseurl'] . '/' . $subdir;
        $modified['path'] = $original['basedir'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subdir;
    }
    return $modified;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'per_user_upload_dir');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function per_user_upload_dir( $original ){
    // use the original array for initial setup
    $modified = $original;
    // set our own replacements
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $subdir = $current_user->user_login;
        $modified['subdir'] = $subdir;
        $modified['url'] = $original['baseurl'] . '/' . $subdir;
        $modified['path'] = $original['basedir'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subdir;
    }
    return $modified;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'per_user_upload_dir');
```

it's worked for me... but is it possible to make another subfolder for all users, like uploads/users/ ? i want to keep all users content into users folder under the upload directory

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution. The uploads folder might get a bit cluttered if many users are uploading. Easy fix is to change:

```
$subdir = $current_user->user_login;
```

to

```
$subdir = 'user_docs/'.$current_user->user_login;
```

The modified example below also only does this for a specific role (instructor)

```
function per_user_upload_dir( $original ){
  $modified = $original;
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('instructor') ) {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $subdir = 'user_docs/'.$current_user->user_login;
      $modified['subdir'] = $subdir;
      $modified['url'] = $original['baseurl'] . '/' . $subdir;
      $modified['path'] = $original['basedir'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subdir;
  }
  return $modified;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'per_user_upload_dir');
```

Answer (score 0):

on one of my sites this code works perfectly however on another it displays this error on the home page:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'per_user_upload_dir' not found or invalid function name in /home/users/xxx/public_html/xxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line

What could be the cause?
The template used is: Jaxon

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265138)